# Remove attribute from controller which was set in config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have written custom attribute to redirect request to `https` when `http` is requested for my `Web API` project as below

```
public class RedirectToHttpAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
            {
                var response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Found, "");
                var uri = new UriBuilder(actionContext.Request.RequestUri);
                uri.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
                uri.Port = 44326;
                response.Headers.Location = uri.Uri;
                actionContext.Response = response;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to set this attributes to all my controllers and actions so I added this in `WebApiConfig`.

```
config.Filters.Add(new RedirectToHttpAttribute());
```

Now there is one controller where I need to allow both `http` and `https`. To make this possible I have to remove above line from `WebApiConfig` and add to all controllers except one in the question. I can do it easily as I have very few controllers but if I had many many controller then what would have been the solution as it is very likely to generate error prone to decorate each controller?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by creating a second attribute, and modifying your existing redirection filter.

Something like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AllowHttpAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class RedirectToHttpsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowHttpAttribute>(false).Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        // Perform the redirect to HTTPS.
    }
}
```

Then on your controller (or action):

```
[AllowHttp]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // ...
}
```